# .NET C# online database from desktop application

Tags: .net, database

I have a .NET desktop application (class library, it's a plugin for another program) which is deployed on multiple computers. I want to gather some usage information from the users and store it in an online database. It's just some text data. What should be a good way to organize this? I have tried to use a MySQL database from my webhost, but that database is only accessible from a localhost and not from different computers. Any advice on this?

Comment: Never connect directly to a database server  over the Internet for too many reasons I won't get into. Just build a simple web-service to collect this data. If you really need something quickly then use something like Azure Mobile Services (a brand-name for a bunch of related services that speed-up development of data applications: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/ )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A web-service sounds as a good solution, but I haven't experience with building web apps or services. Do you have suggestion where to start?

Answer (score -1):

connect your database server Ip(IP, Port) and then add port into the firewall as inbound rules and create a user in database so that only person can access whom you share credentials
Note: 1433 is the default port for database

```
IP,Port= 161.97.137.168,1433
username= NewUser
password= Arslanriaz12345
```

Comment: I downvoted this because we should not be encouraging users to use `sa` (i.e. **root privileges**) in a publically accessible database server where the password will be visible to anyone who snoops inside the application's configuration or disassembly.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it now and you can give thumps up now

Comment: I'm sorry but you're still giving bad advice - a firewall-rule isn't going to stop anything because the port-number is already known and **shared credentials are the problem**, not a solution - just because it's not `sa` doesn't make it automatically safe.

Comment: The allowed database for a SQL user only will be available here nothing else, so he wants to share a specific database, he can give access to a specific database by a SQL user, its completely safe for the rest all things